# Paramiko on Windows with Cygwin OpenSSH doesn't find known_hosts files

Tags: python, ssh, cygwin, paramiko, openssh

I have a setup, where I want to connect from a Windows7 VM to a Linux Server through passwordless SSH with private/public keys.

The SSH connection works fine through the Cygwin terminal.

With Paramiko, I can connect from my client to my host if I accept missing host keys, but if I try to use `known_hosts` instead, I get the error:

> Server XXX not found in known_hosts.

Is Paramiko at all able to read the `known_hosts` file in Windows/Cygwin? Can I somehow provide the path?

My `.ssh` folder is located under `C:\cygwin64\home\<user>\.ssh`.

Thank you a lot for your help,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [`SSHClient.load_system_host_keys`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.load_system_host_keys).

By default, the methods loads `os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts')` file. What does not match your `C:\cygwin64\home\<user>\.ssh` location, as on Windows [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) uses `USERPROFILE` environment variable, which points to `C:\Users\<user>`.

---

You can fix that by:

- Changing your Cygwin configuration somehow (but it can break other things);
- or creating directory junction from `C:\Users\<user>\.ssh` to `C:\cygwin64\home\<user>\.ssh` (probably the most portable solution);
- or explicitly specifying `filename` argument in a call to `SSHClient.load_system_host_keys` (not portable);
- or setting `HOME` environment variable to point to `C:\cygwin64\home\<user>` before running your Python script - `os.path.expanduser` prefers `HOME` to `USERPROFILE` - and Windows does not use `HOME` (can break other things).